# add configMap to deployment config on openshift 4

Tags: path, openshift, configmap

[image]Ive recently started using openshift 4 and im a bit lost.
I have a running pod and I created config map for it but I cant find a way to conect the two.
Ive been told to add the config map to the deployment config of the pod in a specific path.
I tried editing the pod's yaml file to add the file as a volume but got an error when I tried to save the changes.
anyone has an idea how can I add the config map file so I can access it in a specific path in a pod?

Answer (score 1):

The example of adding configmap as a volume to a pod is explained in official [kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#add-configmap-data-to-a-volume)

Below is the sample

```
    volumeMounts:
      - name: config-volume
        mountPath: /etc/config
  volumes:
    - name: config-volume
      configMap:
        # Provide the name of the ConfigMap containing the files you want
        # to add to the container
        name: special-config
```

Comment: do I need to manually create a volume first or does adding it to the yaml file enough? because I've tried what it says in that link and it didnt let me save the changes in the yaml file.

Comment: no need to create volume.  under volumes section you need to mention as ConfigMap attribute and under that name of ConfigMap which you had created.  the file will loaded into location of mountPath you specify following is the example                                                                                  volumeMounts:
      - name: config-volume
        mountPath: /etc/config
  volumes:
    - name: config-volume
      configMap:
        # Provide the name of the ConfigMap containing the files you want
        # to add to the container
        name: special-config

Comment: I need to add these fields to the pod config yaml right?

Comment: because when I try to add them to the pod yaml I get an error saying I can't edit these specific fields. Do you have an idea what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Yes that correct you need to have it in pod definition.   Please share the error

Comment: Please share the yaml definition which is being used

Comment: volumeMounts:
-name: tzlil-client-volume
  mountPath: /conf/ci
volumes:
- name: tzlil-client-volume
configMap:
  name: tzlil-training

Comment: I added the error in the original post

Comment: Details are not clear from the error.  Please share yaml definition which is been used.  Also you can refer k8s documentation for defining ConfigMap